# Pdfcopy return a blank pdf

Tags: pdf, grails, itext

I am trying to copy a existing pdf into another one before writing in it.
here is my code to copy the existing pdf into the ByteOutputStream:

```
        documentPDF.open()

    for(int i=0;i<nbPages;){
           copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++i))
    }
    documentPDF.close()
    copy.close()


   PdfReader reader= new PdfReader("DocDeBase30.pdf");
   reader.selectPages("1-5")
   def documentPDF =new Document()
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
   PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(documentPDF, baos)
   documentPDF.open()
    for(int i=0;i<nbPages;){
           copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++i))
    }
    documentPDF.close()
    copy.close()
    reader.close();
    return baos
```

then i am rendering the pdf file to my view using this step :

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf")
                response.setHeader('Content-disposition', "attachment; filename=intercalaire.pdf")
                response.outputStream << result
                response.outputStream.flush()
   result.close()
```

where result is the returned baos.

the file is openning correctly into my browser but it is blank, nothing as been copied.

for your information, it works fine when i am using a physical path instead of using ByteArrayOutputStream but i have to use a dynamical document in my application so a physical path isn't an option.

Any idea?

thx in advance

Comment: Maybe you are shaving the bytes as explained here: http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Blank-PDF-after-it-is-transfered-through-SMTP-td2228773.html Without seeing the PDF, there is very little else we can tell you about this problem. If the pages are there, but the content of the pages are empty, your server is configured to serve plain text and can't serve binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Bruno Lowagie you were right about shaving the bytes as explained here:http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Blank-PDF-after-it-is-transfered-through-SMTP-td2228773.html

after reading the link, i solved the problem by converting the ByteArrayOutputStream into a byte[]
so here is the code i had to change to solve the problem :

```
        byte[] pdf=result.toByteArray()

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
                response.setHeader('Content-disposition', "attachment; filename=intercalaire.pdf")
                response.outputStream << pdf
                response.outputStream.flush()
   result.close()
```

now it works fine

Thx again Bruno Lowagie